Google_Play_Services_for_AR apk says package is invalid
I used to have Google Play Services for AR installed and working on my Samsung Galaxy tab. At some point it stopped working and whenever I tried to use Google Model Viewer it would attempt to install the Services again. Regular installation through the Play store didn't work so I uninstalled the old package and then went to the Github releases page to get it. The latest version 1.44.0 says it conflicts with other (unspecified) packages. Older APK versions say they are invalid packages when I attempt to install. What do I need to do to get ANY version running again?

It turns out that it was Google Chrome not detecting the AR services properly. I don't know if this helped but I removed both Google Play Services and Google Play Services for AR. I reinstalled Google Play Services via the Play Store, then Google Play Services for AR via the browser prompt. The Samsung browser then worked with AR mode. Still no Chrome.
